# How do i set VerticalAlignment to bottom for range?

Tags: c#, excel

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
Range rng = worksheet.UsedRange;
```

// I found below code but I didn't found ref to both ExcelAlignemt and excel I i missing something which ref required for this

```
rng.VerticalAlignment = ExcelAlignment.xlButtom; //or Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

xlHAlignCenter is in Excel namespace:

```
worksheet.get_Range("A1", "A1").Style.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
```

Now, with your code:

```
rng.Style.VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
```

Answer (score 0):

One should note that for vertical alignment, you should use :

```
XlVAlign.xlVAlignBottom/XlVAlign.xlVAlignTop
```

not

```
XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft
```